# Why recharge the suit when it is powered by the arc reactor

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

In Iron Man 3, after escaping in the boat with Rhodes, we see Stark recharging his suit from a battery. My understanding was that the suit is powered by the arc reactor in his chest. Why does he then use the battery for recharging? Had the arc reactor stopped working? Or is my understanding of the arc reactor wrong?

[image]

Comment: Related, possible dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/35090/3567

Comment: It possibly needed *MORE POWER!* -harharhar-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an experimental suit which was NOT powered by an arc reactor. This seems to be partially related to the fact that it has a lot of independent components and - after detaching themselves - each of those would need its own arc reactor to power itself, which doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: Seems legit....