# Why didn't Stark just shut down the Mk2 armor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2, war-machine

In *Iron Man 2*, Tony spends a lot of time fighting Rhodey in the Stark mansion right after he had a party. Since the Mk2 is still run by J.A.R.V.I.S, couldn't he simply ask J.A.R.V.I.S to shut it down? Why didn't he do that/think of that? He was inebriated, true. But still, Stark is sharper when drunk than most men are when they are completely sober.

Comment: I could have sworn we discussed this already... But I'm only finding the question about how Rhodey fit into the suit.

Comment: i didn't find any such discussion.

Answer (score 9):

Given that the armor's controlling software had been edited by Vanko and a backdoor was installed, I expect that any backdoor Tony had was closed by Vanko.

We also never see War Machine or Iron Patriot talking to J.A.R.V.I.S., so it's possible that that armor (which, if you recall, Stark had intended for Rhodes to have) was running a stripped-down version of the OS.

Earlier, when Rhodes had just stolen the Iron Man armor, Tony was supremely drunk.  When you are drunk, even when you're Tony Stark, you tend to focus on one thing to the exclusion of all else.  Tony focused on beating up Rhodes.  He probably didn't want to order J.A.R.V.I.S. to shut it down or kick him out - then Tony couldn't have fought Rhodes, he would have just killed him (which Tony, even drunk, didn't want).

Keep in mind, though, that Tony ***wanted*** his friend to have the armor.  Rhodes had security access to the vault, was an authorized user for the armor, and it was set up for immediate use.  Tony *could* likely have kicked Rhodes out of the armor (had he wanted to and been sober enough to consider it) but he didn't truly desire to do so.  In his mind, fighting for the armor (and learning how to use it in the process) would make Rhodes better at using it to fight evil (recall, Tony was *certain* he was going to die soon) and less likely to hand it over to others.  Basic psychology: the harder you fight for something, the less willing you are to give it up.

Comment: Hammer didn't get his hands on the armor right away. I'd guess there was a period of 12 to 24 hours, minimum, that Tony could have had JARVIS shut the suit down, not to mention before, during or immediately after Tony and James fight.

Comment: @Xantec: The question was about during the fight.  That said, Tony spent a good portion of that time unconscious and (as has been established [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/35036/656)) he wanted Rhodie to have the suit anyway.

Comment: This question is asking about the initial fight, when Rhodes took the suit: `And he was inebriated, true. But still, Stark is sharper when drunk than most men are when they are completely sober.` Vanko and Hammer hadn't touched the suit yet at that point. The answer you linked to seems it would make more sense here than on the other question.

Comment: @Jeff - I can understand the confusion. I edited the question to reflect exactly the part I was talking about. I was talking about the events well before Hammer/Vanko got his hands on the Mk2. Tony fought Rhodey 1-on-1 in the Stark mansion for quite some time. At that point the Mk2 was still controlled by JARVIS. Why didn't he get JARVIS to shut it down?

Comment: Hmm. His drunken state could've been a factor which made him focus on using the suit rather than using JARVIS. So are you saying this was Stark's way of "initiating" Rhodey sorta?

Comment: @ash_k29: Exactly.  Tony wasn't really trying to *win*, he just had his Irish up and wanted a good brawl.  Haven't you ever been angry and just wanted to punch something?  Now mix in drunk and superpowers :-)